# How can a live distribution be made to access DVDs?

Tags: live-usb, 18.04, dvd

I want to back up one of my DVDs (using `dd`). I am on a live USB distribution (18.04) because I'm using someone else's computer that has a DVD drive and I don't want to overwrite their stuff. All of the instructions I've seen online seem to suggest starting by installing `libdvd-pkg`, but when I try to do this I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libdvd-pkg
```

How can I get this installed (and anything else needed before using `dd`)?

Comment: Sorry `dd` requires installation? Since when? And be very very careful. `dd` can destroy a partition with 1 typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to install `libdvd-pkg`

You need the repository, where `libdvd-pkg` resides, `multiverse`. When you are adding a repository, you should also add `universe` with many useful packages, for example `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, which is useful for playing multimedia.

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

In earlier versions you should run

```
sudo apt update
```

but it is automatically run via `add-apt-repository` in 18.04 LTS.

Now you should be able to install with

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
```

### How to make `libdvd-pkg` survive shutdown and reboot.

You can do this in a live-only drive, but it will disappear at shutdown or reboot. If you want it to survive, you should create a **persistent live** system.

The following links describe how to create a persistent live drive

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

### How to clone a DVD

If you want to create an image file of a DVD disk or clone it to another DVD disk, I suggest that you use a safer tool than `dd`. **`k3b`** is a good tool for that purpose, and you get it from the repository `universe`

```
sudo apt install k3b
```